# Keywords Field in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm beginner in Django. In my model I have a Field named keywords that I want to store keywords in it (separated by comma).

A user may enter a compound keyword `"learn Django"` or `"Django model-Fields"`, and also I want to have the possibility to set a `max_length` for every keyword. And a `max ?` of keywords!

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this feature to any model using [django taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or a similar app. Using an existing app also means you don't have to repeat the work they've already done, such as producing a 'similar items' queryset.

Comment: It seems that Django taggit is a great tool, it provides what I want exactly, I'll try it and hope it works fine. Thanks