# How to store a list of string (tags or keywords) in a django model field?

Tags: django, tags, listfield

I have these models:

```
class Author(model):
    user = OneToOneField(CustomUser)
    other_filed = CharField(...)


class Post(Model):
    author = ForeignKey(Author, on_del..)
    title = CharField(...)
    # keywords field to be inserted in a form and stored
```

As already described, I need to field for the keyword related to each post written by an author. While I need something simple to avoid complexities, I prefer to be able to restrict the length of each keyword and the number of keywords. 
I have read 
[Keywords Field in Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132272/keywords-field-in-django-model)
and 
[What is the most efficient way to store a list in the Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110153/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-a-list-in-the-django-models)
and a few other articles but do not seem to be able to decide what should I do

suppose I will find a way to store it. Why do I need it?
At this stage, I only need to populate the keywords meta tag in the head part of the html of the page related to the article. I may, in the future, use these keywords to search and find an article.

Comment: Please don't. Make another model, like `Tag`, and use a many-to-many field between the two.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Suppose I won't. How can an author add a new tag to the `Tag` model?

Comment: then you are likely violating 1NF of relational database normalization forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem SO what is the solution? To provide the ability to each author to add tags to his/her article, even new tags. And to empower to restrict the length of each of their tags and the number of their tags

Comment: if you are using postgres, you can use [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Comment: An ArrayField is an option, but as Willem mentioned, a many-to-many relationship to another keyword model is much better, as it allows a keyword to be shared across multiple posts and makes your code much more readable (e.g. `some_keyword.posts.all()` would give you all related posts with the same keyword). @AminBa there's no reason you should not use an M2M relationship.

Comment: @dirkgroten Then, how should I let authors add a new tag? Like what we see in stackoverflow. When asking a question, we can use the already available tags or (if authorized) add a new tag to the tag repo.

Comment: In your view, either associate an existing tag or create a new one if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @dirkgroten How can I pass it to the view if I am using modelform?

Comment: modelform for many-to-many field does not allow to add a non-existing object

Comment: and it is possible to query array field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield